# Angular 2 - Pass data from parent component to child component on button clicked at parent component

Tags: angular, components

At parentComponenet.html

```
</div><button(click)="discoverClicked()">Discover</button></div>
<child-component></child-component>
```

At parentComponent.ts

```
export class parentComponent implements OnInit {
    discoverClicked(){
       //send data to childComponent
    }
}
```

At childComponent.ts

```
export class childComponent implements OnInit {
    discoverClicked(){
       //received data from parent component
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do as per described above?

Comment: How is the child component rendered? Most likely `discoverClicked` would update some property on the parent that you would bind to the child component in the parent template

Comment: @ExplosionPills I have updated parentComponent.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depends on your data, one way of doing so is to introduce some variable, for example in parent component:

```
@Component(...)
export class ParentComponent {
    private data: any;

    discoverClicked(){
        // do the thing
        this.data = "some data not matter how you got it";
    }
}
```

And in `parent-component.html`:

```
</div><button(click)="discoverClicked()">Discover</button></div>
<child-component [data]=data></child-component>
```

Then in child component:

```
@Component(...)
export class ChildComponent {

    @Input('data')
    set data(data: any) {
        //do whatever you want with your data here, this data will be passed from parent component
    }
}
```

If you need more complex behavior you can make some service which will hold data for you and then pass it to child component, for example:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    private _data: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    public setData(data: any){
        this._data.next(data);
    }

    public getData(): Observable<any> {
        return this._data.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Then in parent component:

```
@Component(...)
export class ParentComponent {

    constructor(private dataService: DataService){}

    discoverClicked(){
        // do the thing
        this.dataService.setData("any data that you want");
    }
}
```

And in child component:

```
@Component(...)
export class ChilComponent{

    constructor(private dataService: DataService){
        this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data=>{
            // Do whatever you want with your data
        }
    }

}
```

P.S.
Don't forget to provide service somewhere and unsubscribe from data in child component.

Answer (score 0):

add this, let-c="close" let-d="dismiss" in your parent HTML tag.
Then on button click, pass 'd' as an argument. and in ts file, listen to the argument and call function d() whenever you want to dismiss the NgbModal